# Asp.Net output Caching not working

Tags: asp.net, caching, configuration, outputcache

I'm trying to cache some of my ASP.Net pages.

I followed this tutorial and managed to make it work properly : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfw2210t%28v=VS.90%29.aspx.

Now, when applying the exact same technic on my ASP.Net website, I have absolutely no cache whatsoever... When hitting F5 on my page, it simply reloads the same page again and again...

I added this on top of my aspx page :

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="15" VaryByParam="none"%>
```

And then on my Load method, basically writing the current time to check if it's updated or not, just like the above example... Unfortunately, the time changes everytime I hit F5...

What am I missing here ? Some configuration or ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: do you place OutputCache it at the top, but after the @Page declaration, right ?

Comment: Actually, I tried both of these placements ! Never worked tho...

Comment: its working fine with me, with out do anything else. What iis do you run ?

Comment: I'm using the one installed with Visual Studio 2010 (Asp.Net version : 4.0.30319.272).

Comment: It's also working perfectly fine with a simple "hello world" project.... I think there is some configuration or something else within my project, but cannot find something related to this problem...

Comment: if you run it from the visual studio and opens and close the small web server that comes with, then for sure the cache is clear every time you press f5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that our project used a framework that called the following code :

```
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1));
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

That was the source of my issues...

Comment: What framework was it and how did you find that this was the issue?

Comment: It was a private framework from another company we're using as a base for our Asp.Net Website. I've seen that it was possible to disable the cache by adding those lines, so, just to be sure, I made a quick search in this private framework's source code. Bingo, by disabling those lines, since the cache wasn't disabled anymore, it worked !